# how to THREE.Sprite change pivot point?

Tags: three.js, pivot, sprite, transform

I want to set rotate **transform-origin** to the **left** of sprite, not center, when towards the camera and keep the angle to horizontal.

```
      // 2d
      var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas)
      texture.needsUpdate = true
      var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ 
        map: texture, 
        transparent: true,
        useScreenCoordinates: false,
      })
      var actualSize = 10 / size.h
      var w = size.w / size.h * actualSize
      var h = actualSize
      var mesh = new THREE.Sprite(material)
      mesh.scale.set(w, h, 1)
```

Comment: This is not a proper solution - an ugly hack - I had the same problem and just made my sprite two times wider using transparent background...